# Compute a Gramm matrix in MATLAB without loops

Tags: matlab, svm

I have a matrix `X(10000, 800)`. I want to compute gramm matrix `K(10000,10000)`, where `K(i,j)= exp(-(X(i,:)-X(j,:))^2)`.

First i used double for loop, but then it just hangs forever. 
Then I tried this:

```
[N d] = size(X);
aa = repmat(X',[1 N]);
bb = repmat(reshape(X',1,[]),[N 1]);
K = reshape((aa-bb).^2, [N*N d]);
K = reshape(sum(D,2),[N N]);
```

But then it uses a lot of extra space and I run out of memory very soon.
Is there any efficient vectorized method for this.
I am sure there must be something as this is quite a standard intermediate step for many kernel svms and also in image processing.

Comment: please be clearer with the expression of this Gramm matrix.

Comment: Both codes seem wrong to me. In the first one you take second power a row vector and assign vectors to scalars. In the second code snippet you take sum of `D`, which is not defined. There is also not exponent there, while you have exp in the first code line. Gram matrix looks like all possible inner products of vectors. Why do you calculate exp?

Comment: sorry for confusion. In the first code I meant to take square of norm of the distance, so it should be square of magnitude, actually this was just to explain what Gramm matrix is. In second snippet it was K instead of D.

Answer (score 3):

Use [**pdist2**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/pdist2.html) or pdist. Note that pdist2 from Matlab is just [slow](https://gist.github.com/31bb963e0a2d7556b432.git)...
[image: Matlab cosine distance is way slow]

Code:

```
X = rand(100, 3);
K = squareform(pdist(X, 'euclidean'));
K = exp(-K.^2);
```

I'll write this for the more general case where you have *two* matrices and you want to find all the distances.
`(x-y)^2 = x'x - 2x'y + y'y` If you want to compute the Gram matrix, you need all combinations of differences.

```
X = rand(100, 3);
Y = rand(50, 3);
A = sum(X .* X, 2);
B = -2 *X * Y';
C = sum(Y .* Y, 2);
K = bsxfun(@plus, A, B);
K = bsxfun(@plus, K, C);
K = exp(-K);
```

## EDIT: Speed-comparison

### Code

```
% http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109826/compute-a-gramm-matrix-in-matlab-without-loops/24407122#24407122
function time_gramm()
% I have a matrix X(10000, 800). I want to compute gramm matrix K(10000,10000), where K(i,j)= exp(-(X(i,:)-X(j,:))^2).
X = rand(100, 800);

%% The straight-forward pdist solution.
tic;
K = squareform(pdist(X, 'euclidean'));
K1 = exp(-K .^2);
t1 = toc;
fprintf('pdist took \t%d seconds\n', t1);

%% The vectorized solution
tic;
A = sum(X .* X, 2);
B = -2 * X * X';
K = bsxfun(@plus, A, B);
K = bsxfun(@plus, K, A');
K2 = exp(-K);
t2 = toc;
fprintf('Vectorized solution took \t%d seconds.\n', t2);

%% The not-so-smart triple-loop solution
tic;
N = size(X, 1);
K3 = zeros(N, N);
for i=1:N
    %     fprintf('Running outer loop for i= %d\n', i);
    for j=1:N
        xij = X(i,:) - X(j,:);
        xij = norm(xij, 2);
        xij = xij ^ 2;
        K3(i,j) = -xij;
        %         d = X(i,:) - X(j,:); % Alternative way, twice as fast but still
        %         orders of magnitude slower than the other solutions.
        %         K3(i,j) = exp(-d * d');
    end
end
K3 = exp(K3);
t3 = toc;
fprintf('Triple-nested loop took \t%d seconds\n', t3);
%% Assert results are the same...
assert(all(abs(K1(:) - K2(:)) < 1e-6 ));
assert(all(abs(K1(:) - K3(:)) < 1e-6 ));
end
```

### Results

I ran the above code with N=100

```
pdist took  8.600000e-03 seconds
Vectorized solution took    3.916000e-03 seconds.
Triple-nested loop took     2.699330e-01 seconds
```

Notice that at 100th the requested size of the question, the performance of the code suggested in the other answer (`O(m^2 n)`) is two orders of magnitude slower. By the time, I plugged in 100k as the size of the `X` matrix, it took much, much longer than I cared to wait.

The performance on the full-sized problem (`X = rand(10000, 800)`) was this:

```
pdist took  5.470632e+01 seconds
Vectorized solution took    1.141894e+01 seconds.
```

### Comment

The vectorized solution took 11s, Matlab's pdist took 55s and the manual solution suggested in the other sample never finished.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the straightforward formula for this?
For element `K(i, j) = exp( sum_{k=0}^{n} (X(i, k) - X(j, k))^2`.
So, that's two outer loops for `i` and `j` and an inner loop for `k`. The time complexity is `O(m^2 n)`, where there are `m` lines and `n` columns in `X`. The space complexity is `O(1)` since you don't use any more space than just the `X` and `K` matrices to calculate the answer.

Have you tried this and is it really so slow?

Comment: K = zeros(N, N);
    for i=1:N
        fprintf('Running outer loop for i= %d\n', i);
        for j=1:N
            xij = X(i,:) - X(j,:);
            xij = norm(xij, 2);
            xij = xij ^ 2;
            K(i,j) = -xij;
        end
    end
    K = exp(K);
<br/> I tried this, but then it took me more than an hour. So, I thought some vectorized method if there is any should speed up.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know of any magic vectorization. Also, `norm(xij, 2)^2` is the same as `dot(xij, xij)`, so you could write that `K(i, j) = -(dot(xij, xij))`. Other than that, I feel that you could try writing a MEX file (C module) instead of a funky vectorized solution. It's very straightforward! :) Here's a link to get you started http://cnx.org/content/m12348/latest/